# Trace/BPT trap: 5 and Gnuplot/Text Edit, ... on Mavericks

Tags: macos, macports

I need to use gnuplot and a bunch of other stuff, so I installed MacPorts on Mavericks. After installing the packages, if I try to plot something I get the `Trace/BPT trap: 5` error. Reinstalling XQuartz didn't fix the problem. Do you know how could I fix this? I tried various methods suggested online but nothing worked. Thanks!

Comment: Could you expand on what 'various methods' you did?

Comment: I reinstalled MacPorts and Homebrew, I reinstalled XQuartz and I checked if there was something strange in .bash_profile